# Trouble loading django admin template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am very new to Django and, following their tutorial, I am having issues loading a custom admin template (specifically, I am having trouble at the bottom of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/).

I have updated my `TEMPLATE_DIRS` so it looks like:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/myname/Developer/Eclipse/templates/admin',
)
```

I have also tried:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        '/Users/myname/Developer/Eclipse/templates/admin/base_site.html',
    )
```

The path for where I am storing this custom template follows:

"/Users/myname/Developer/Eclipse/templates/admin"   (copy and pasted directly from file info)

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you don't use your `admin` folder for all the templates use this (I guess you want to overwrite admin templae. So `admin` folder should be subfolder of your template folder):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/myname/Developer/Eclipse/templates/',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)
```